# Why I can't access via SSH to my AWS Instance after rebooting?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can't access to my instance via SSH after rebooting.

Also if Instance Status is running.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The public ip address of the EC2 instance will change after the reboot if the instance do not have an elastic ip address assigned. You can check the new public ip address on the EC2 console. If you attach an Elastic ip address, it will not change after reboot.

#### To determine your instance's public IPv4 addresses using the console

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Instances.
3. Select your instance. In the details pane, get the public IP address from the IPv4 Public IP field, and get the external DNS hostname from the Public DNS (IPv4) field.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

#### Here is how you can attach an elastic ip address.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html