# Can no longer connect to AWS EC2 Free Tier Windows 0x204

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a AWS EC2 Free Tier Windows instance.  At first, I could connect from my Mac Laptop using Microsoft Remote Desktop.  I had used the suggested security zone from the Wizard, with the choice of "My IP".

Then, I tried to connect from my iPad on the same home network.  No luck.  Said the account password was incorrect (it wasn't).  So, I tried changing the security zone to "Anywhere".

Bottom line is that now I cannot connect from either my laptop or my iPad.  I can change the security zone to "My IP" or "Anywhere" but neither works.  Maybe I should just trash this instance and start over?

Comment: Just to be clear, now no matter what I do, I get the 0x204 error when I try to connect.

Comment: Are you able to ping the instance?

Comment: my guess is your instance's public ip address may have been changed. did you restart the instance

Comment: The AWS Free Tier is a billing discount. It would have no impact on your usage of the instance or operating system.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 instances gets a public ip address (if you have requested during launch) automatically. But the auto assigned public ip address will change when the instance stopped and started again. if you don't want the public ip address to change, you need to assign an elastic ip address to your instance.

I have answered this question for another user.

Reference: (Read the answer Arun K)
[Why I can't access via SSH to my AWS Instance after rebooting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209188/why-i-cant-access-via-ssh-to-my-aws-instance-after-rebooting/59209318#59209318)

Comment: Rebooting Amazon EC2 instances does _not_ change the associated public IP address. This is because the same virtual machine continues to run — it is merely the Operating System that has done a reboot. However, if an instance is **Stopped**, then the public IP address can change.

Comment: thanks , updated my answer. I actually knew this, It just didn't come to my mind. i used to stop and start instances (instead of rebooting) in order facilitate moving the instance to a new hardware (when requested by aws).

Comment: My instance is currently running.  I checked the current public IP address as described in the reference.  But, I still cannot connect.  Ping fails.

Comment: for the ping to work, you need allow `ICMP` traffic in your security group. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance

Comment: Add a rule to the security group as mentioned in the stackover flow reference above.